# John the Ripper MaxLen

Tags: password-cracking

From the [documentation](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/CONFIG.shtml)

> MaxLen = LENGTH
>
> Maximum password length to try. The default is 8 (or CHARSET_LENGTH as
>   defined in src/params.h at compile time).

I've compiled it to support up to 62 characters, modified john.conf, but when running `john` it returns:

```
Incompatible charset file: $JOHN/alnum.chr
```

That's when using `--incremental=alnum`, but happens with any method. Why does this happens? Which are the exact modifications or parameters to support 62 characters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The included charset files are based on the default maximum length. You'll need to generate charsets for your target length:

```
john --pot=rockyou.txt --make-charset=alnum62.chr
```

Existing files will be overwritten, so you'll probably want to choose a different filename from the default.

More [in this thread](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2013/02/05/2).

Comment: and .... when I run the custom charset, it will use the words in rockyou.txt? Or the characters?

Comment: Well, it's generating Markov stats by analyzing the combinations of characters in the list. So it's a little of both. :)

Comment: and what if I do `john --stdout --incremental=MODE | john --pot=- --make-charset=alnum62.chr` I put `--pot=-` but how would it be?